# RenderTargetBitmap creates blurry image

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I have 2 controls, one that displays some vector graphics, this works fine. My second control that displays vector graphics as a bitmap is the problem. I am using a RenderTargetBitmap to create a bitmap that is the required size and then drawing a scaled version of the vector graphics to it. However, it comes out blurry.

```
double scale = Math.Min(width == 0 ? 1 : targetWidth / frameworkElement.Width, height == 0 ? 1 : targetHeight / frameworkElement.Height);
frameworkElement.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

if (width > 0 && height > 0)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap scaledBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)targetWidth , (int)targetHeight , 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    scaledBitmap.Render(metaImage);

    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = scaledBitmap;
    _visualChild = image;
}
```

Where the frameworkElement is a extended FrameworkElement that can display vector graphics.
The image below shows the difference between the two controls displayed at the same size, the raw vector graphics displayed inside a viewbox on the right. And the vector graphics scaled and rendered to a RenderTargetBitmap on the left.

[image]

I have also tried:

1. Programmatically creating a viewbox, setting its visual child to the vector graphics frame work element, measuring and arranging then drawing viewbox (which is basicly exactly what is being displayed in the right image) to the RenderTargetBitmap.
2. Creating two RenderTargetBitmaps, Rendering the vector graphics to the first at the desired size of the vector graphics. Then drawing a scaled version of the first RenderTargetBitmap to the second using DrawingGroup and DrawingVisual. This allowed me to set the RenderOptions.

   ```
    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(group, BitmapScalingMode.Fant);
   ```

But the Fant option produced the same results and other options seemed to produce worse results.

Also tried setting the edge mode in the render options but you only get the option between EdgeMode.Unspecified and EdgeMode.Aliased.

How can I draw exactly the image that would be displayed by the vector graphics control when its inside a viewbox to a bitmap?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I'm having the exact same issues, and have tried most of the same things.

Comment: @misnomer No, I'm afraid not. I ended up rendering a larger bitmap and letting wpf scale it automatically to work around the issue.

Comment: Although it is very late, may be [this link](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/12/High-Resolution-Printing-of-WPF-3D-Visuals.html) will help